# Remove prefix from subject header in index view

Tags: mutt, maildrop

I subscribed to several mailing lists that prefix the `Subject:`
header with a fixed string like `[list-foo]`. This clutters my index
view and limits the usable space.

I'd like to strip this `[list-foo]` header from the index view.
What's the best way to achieve that? Maybe a regular expression can
be hooked into the `index_format` setting? I don't necessarily need
to strip the prefix permanently, it's sufficient to not display it
in the index. It may still show up in the pager and be included in
responses.

I know that Claws-Mail has a function that does exactly this. It's called *Simplify Subject RegExp*.

If this is not possible using mutt I guess one option would be to
permanently change the headers using a mail filter like maildrop
(which I use for sorting, though not for header manipulation). Feel
free to also add a solution that uses maildrop to strip the prefix
from the headers.

Answer (score 2):

Munging the subject is possible with `subjectrx`. Available since mutt 1.8.0.

[Mutt manual, 12. Display Munging](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#display-munging)